# Validating script in oracle

Tags: oracle

To validate whether particular table is present in the database, we query it as

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.getddl('TABLE','TABLE_NAME','OWNER') FROM dba_objects where rownum = 1;
```

To validate whether particular procedure is present in the database, we query it as

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.getddl('PROCEDURE','PROCEDURE_NAME','OWNER') FROM dba_objects where rownum = 1;
```

To validate the sql script, what would be the query to validate whether script is present in database or not. My sql script named with "new1.sql".

Comment: What is the query to validate the sql script present in database, just insert script named with "new1.sql". Is there any query to validate it ?

Comment: The database does not store SQL files; they are stored in the file system wherever you have put them (i.e. locally or on a server). When the database runs the script then the text of the script is passed to the database and that is run but it does not store the script file that you have run.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46343896/1509264

Comment: You may also find that the database does not know about the full text of a "script" but only knows about individual statements within the script as they may be passed one-by-one from the SQL client program you are using to the database and each statement is run within the same transaction.